# Sheidim: are they fact, or fiction?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, mysticism-kabbalah, sheidim-demons

Are there really such thing as sheidim? If so, what are they? Please include sources.

Comment: I believe (someone please correct me if I'm wrong) that there is a particular sheid by the name of "Yosef Sheida" that was mentioned in the gemara as helping chazal. Apparently, the Maharal also used this sheid in the creation of the golem (or so they say......). I'll work on sources for this.

Comment: see the book Minchas Yehuda by Rabbi Yehuda Fatya. incredible accounts he witnessed.

Comment: http://rechovot.blogspot.com/2013/03/a-different-approach-to-sheidim.html

Comment: Demons do not exist

Comment: @HodofHod The Golem of Prague is generally believed to be a hoax. See *Magic, Mysteries & Mysticism* by Rabbi Mordechai Zvi Trenk, the chapter titled *The Golem of Prague*.

Answer (score 31):

Unless we assume it is all allegory, the Talmud is replete with references to Mazikin, aka Sheidim, and they sure sound real.

Rabbis even had conversations with them (e.g. [Chullin 105b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=31&daf=105b&format=pdf)), provided a way to see them ([Berachot 6a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=6&format=pdf)), overheard them ([Succa 28a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=7&daf=28&format=pdf)) and established laws based on their existence (e.g. [Berachot 3b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=3b&format=pdf) and [Pesachim 100b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=100b&format=pdf)).

King Solomon and the king of Sheidim, Asmodai, were acquaintences, so to speak. Read all about it in [Gittin 68b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=19&daf=68b&format=pdf). The Egyptians were adept at both magic and harnessing sheidim ([Sanhedrin 67b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=67b&format=pdf)).

Abaye decreed upon the Mazikin that they should no longer bother us, which may explain why we don't know much about their existence today.

Comment: Source Request - Where did Abaye decree that Mazikim should no longer bother us?

Comment: @Menachem: Pesachim 112b, bottom. Although it doesn't say that he addressed all of the mazikin, just their queen Igras bas Machalas.

Comment: @Alex: thanks. And it appears that the Gemara continues that he wasn't successful, and sometimes they do still end up in civilized places.

Comment: @Menachem which is probably why R' Yoel Baal Shem had problems with them later.

Comment: @HodofHod: This would also fit in with the Minchat Elazar's statement that the Baal Shem Tov permanently banned them from civilized areas (after a period of using them for his own purposes): Divre Torah Vol 9, chapter 89 -- http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=4714&pgnum=71

Comment: @Menachem Interesting. The Previous Lubavitcher Rebbe in his [memoirs](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15614&pgnum=199) says that this was done by R' Yoel Baal Shem of Zamoshtch.

Comment: @HodofHod: My understanding is that was a localized ban, limited to the house in the story. As the story says (on page 207) - "From that day onwards, those dreadful creatures, the demons, were never again either seen or heard in that house." - http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15614&st=&pgnum=207

Comment: @menachem aha. That does make sense.

Comment: This doesn't cite any opinions about if it is all an allegory or not. How does it answer the question?

Comment: This draws a false dichotomy by stating that unless the Talmud is allegorical, that demons exist. This presupposes that the Talmud is correct. In reality, [all the Geonim, and most Rishonim did not consider the Talmud's authority to extend to matters of realia](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53349/belief-in-midrashim/53351#53351). Indeed, such major Rishonim as Rambam and Meiri rejected the existence of demons, indicating that they probably thought the reasoning in this post is flawed.

Comment: My sources relate that a Rabbi conversed with a sheid or overheard one speaking. If it isn't allegory, and it actually happened as stated, then I conclude the sheid must exist. The only other option I can think of is to assert the Rabbi was hallucinating, which I do not find persuasive. This isn't comparable to scientific matters where we may dispute Talmudic explanations of phenomena -- here we are discussing a documented empirical observation.

Comment: @barry or lying. There are liars in every religion. Judaism is no exception. I've heard theres a mikubel who lives a few blocks away from me who can see Sheidim. And there are plenty of people who hallucinate about spiritual stuff. Just search "why I became Christian and you'll find thousands of" I felt God/Jesus" story's. Same with Islam and Judaism. Peoples minds are fragile things.

Answer (score 17):

The gemara clearly mentions sheidim, and there were certainly Rishonim (e.g. Rashi) and Acharonim who took these mentions literally.

The Rambam takes them non-literally, as he writes in Moreh Nevuchim 1:7 and in his perush haMishnayot to Avodah Zarah 4:7.

The Kotzker Rebbe has a famous elu veElu in which he explains that the Rambam effectively paskened sheidim out of existence. However, if one looks at the actual words of the Rambam, it seems rather unlikely that the Rambam would agree to this harmonization.

I discuss this in depth, giving the text of the actual sources, in [this parshablog post](http://parsha.blogspot.com/2010/10/demons-on-ark-and-kotzkers-famous-elu.html):
http://parsha.blogspot.com/2010/10/demons-on-ark-and-kotzkers-famous-elu.html

Comment: The Kotzker was not the only one to offer an "eilu v'eilu" approach. The Minchas Elazar offers a different approach based on a gemara in Pesachim and on the fact that the Moreh Nevuchim was written with a particular audience in mind. (What he does with the Peirush Hamishnayos reference, I don't know.)
Also, it should be noted that there do exist other rishonim that criticize the Rambam for this statement.

Comment: Careful, if you deny Sheidim they might come to attack you!!! See http://parsha.blogspot.com/2011/09/was-ibn-ezra-killed-by-demons.html

Comment: @RebChaimHaQoton כללא דמילתא כל דקפיד קפדי בהדיה ודלא קפיד לא קפדי בהדיה ומיהו למיחש מיבעי

Comment: @jake which rishonim criticize the Rambam on this?

Comment: @jake Correct. The audience in mind was nevuchim (perplexed); which is in the title. They had problems believing this stuff, so the Rambam had to reconcile it for them, so they would say least believe in the Torah, if there belief wasn't strong enough to believe everything whether they understand or not. I don't think you can learn from moreh nevuchim what the Rambam held.

Comment: I don't think Rambam in PHM says anything about taking anything non0literally, he simply disagrees. Rambam along with the [majority of Geonim and Rishonim did not feel that the beliefs of Chazal were generally binding, except in matters of strict halakha](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53349/belief-in-midrashim/53351#53351)

Answer (score 9):

The straightandforward understanding of Chazal is that there are sheidim and that they are a troublemaking species which are somewhat physical, somewhat spiritual.

> Our Rabbis taught: Six things are said
>   concerning demons: in regard to three,
>   they are like the ministering angels;
>   and in regard to three like human
>   beings.‘In regard to three they are
>   like ministering angels’: they have
>   wings like ministering angels; and
>   they fly from one end of the world to
>   on the other like ministering angels;
>   and they…hear from behind the Veil
>   like ministering angels. ‘And in
>   regard to three, they are like human
>   beings’: they eat and drink like human
>   beings, they propagate like human
>   beings, and they die like human
>   beings. (Hagigah 16a, Traditional
>   Press)
>
> Our Rabbis taught: there are three
>   reasons why one must not go into a
>   ruin: because of suspicion, of falling
>   debris and of demons [sheidim]… To one
>   [person] an evil spirit may show
>   itself and harm him; to two it may
>   show itself, but without harming them;
>   to three it will not even show itself
>   (Berakoth 3a, 43b, Traditional Press,
>   New York City New York, translated by
>   Maurice Simon, M.A., edited by Rabbi
>   Dr. I. Epstein B.A., Ph.D., D. Lit.)

http://machzikeihadas.blogspot.com/2008/09/endangered-species-sheidim-and-habitat.html

Comment: What about the Rambam?

Comment: I don't know of a source where the Rambam discusses this explicitly but his son R. Avraham does as is mentioned in the link. It seems to me his hypothesis isn't obvious.

Comment: The question was whether they exist. Citing a Chazal only answers the question, if Chazal's authority extends to non-halachic matters. This crucial point should be edited in. For a variety of sources that state that this is not the case, see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53349/belief-in-midrashim/53351#53351.

Answer (score 8):

The Rambam, practically alone among the major commentators, has the almost unique view that sheidim do not exist, and the entire idea was a simple superstition, played upon by the Sages for use parables and other concepts. Consequently, he interpreted all the Gemaros and Midrashim that mention sheidim as allegories or the like. Though some of his interpretations can be found in Moreh Nevuchim, we unfortunately do not have his explanations to all the Aggados in Shas, though he did at one time plan on compiling such a book (see his introduction to the Moreh). His son Rav Avraham seems to hold his father's views on the matter. See, for example, his introduction to Aggados, printed in most editions of Ein Yaakov. The Meiri, in his running commentary of the Gemara, makes a point of trying to explain how the Rambam may have learned these Gemaras.
The vast majority of Rishonim and Acharonim, however, chief among them the Ramban, are of the opinion that sheidim do in fact exist. This is primarily based on the hundreds of references in Chazal to sheidim, which certainly seem to exist. The Ramchal in Derech Hashem explains that sheidim are somewhat physical and somewhat spiritual beings.
The Tannaim and Amoraim seemed to frequently meet and even interact with sheidim. The question remains: Why do we not see or detect sheidim nowadays? The simple answer is that we are not on the spiritual level to notice such beings. My Grandfather shlita told me that Rabbi Ruderman zt"l, late Rosh Yeshivah of Ner Yisroal, suggested a different reason. The Gemara in Pesachim 112b relates that certain great Sages were on the spiritual stature to decree, as it were, that the sheidim not reveal themselves on certain days of the week. Rav Ruderman suggested, perhaps somewhat in jest, that the very fact that the Rambam thought shaidim do not exist caused, as it were, their disappearance.

Comment: http://parsha.blogspot.com/2010/10/demons-on-ark-and-kotzkers-famous-elu.html

Comment: By the way, this is a misrepresentation of the Meiri. He does not "explain how Rambam would understand the Gemara". Rather, he himself explains every Gemara involving demons as referring to anything besides demons, as he obviously did not believe in demons himself.

Comment: It's worth noting that in "Torah, Chazal and Science" Rav Meiselman has an entire appendix devoted to R' Avraham ben haRambam's letter and the question of its authenticity. He quotes the text and includes variants based on various manuscripts.

Answer (score 7):

The Previous Lubavitcher Rebbe, in [his memoirs](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15614&pgnum=199), recounts a story about the Alter Rebbe's (Rabbi Schneur Zalman, the first Chabad Rebbe) great-grandfather, R' Baruch Batlan. Apparently, he was a tenant in a building which became inhabited by sheidim after the passing of the building's owners. After trying several ways to remove them, his Rebbe, R' Yoel, the Baal Shem of Zamoshtch, came and called them to a "Din Torah". The story is fascinating in its entirety, but in short, the Beis Din [paskened that they must leave the building](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15614&st=&pgnum=207), so they did.

Interestingly, it appears that they are held by the ban to avoid inhabited places, and only violated it in this case on the orders of Ashmedai. The sheidim held that they were the legal heirs to the building's owners, because the owners' curses had created them.

This story took place in the mid-1600's

Comment: Very similar to the story in Chullin 105b: הנהו שקולאי דהוו דרו חביתא דחמרא בעו לאיתפוחי אותבוה תותי מרזיבא פקעה אתו לקמיה דמר בר רב אשי אפיק שיפורי שמתיה אתא לקמיה אמר ליה אמאי תעביד הכי אמר ליה היכי אעביד כי אותביה באונאי אמר ליה את בדוכתא דשכיחי רבים מאי בעית את הוא דשנית זיל שלים אמר ליה השתא נמי ליקבע לי מר זימנא ואפרע קבע ליה זימנא כי מטא זימנא איעכב כי אתא אמר ליה אמאי לא אתית בזמנך אמר ליה כל מילי דצייר וחתים וכייל ומני לית לן רשותא למשקל מיניה עד דמשכחינן מידי דהפקרא

Comment: "Din Torah"How does that work?

Comment: @sam translation?Into english

Answer (score 5):

It is true that the Talmud Bavli clearly mentions shedim in many places. As in other areas, they followed the science of the time, so something that seems unscientific now was a reasonable belief back then.
However, that doesn't mean they were completely wrong. They felt there were certain harmful invisible forces that existed in the world and that one must protect himself from. Although we wouldn't call these forces 'demons' nowadays, we do know of other microscopic forces that can cause harm. So if they said one should wash his hands to get rid of "ruach rah" or "bad spirits", it wasn't exactly wrong. Washing hands does help get rid of the "bad spirits" of bacteria. While its true not all cases can be explained like this, the overall belief in 'demons' can often be connected to many real phenomena.

Comment: Most of the mysticism of the Gemora can be explained with knowledge of things which can not be directly seen by the human eye.

Comment: I've never seen any poskim permitting things based on such Svaros. In that case, one would not have to wash one's hands before bread with a keli, just use a good disinfectant.

Comment: It was given as an example. There are other reasons we wash our hands, such as "beriyah chadashah", that we're like a new creation when we wake up. Anyways, a gzeira can stay in a certain way, even if there are reasons to do it differently. Though most halachos relating to 'shedim' and 'zugos' are not in fact kept today, sonmething the rishonim already discuss.

Comment: Your answer is based on the assumption that sheidim indeed do not exist. You bring no proof to this assumption, so you didn't answer the OP's question. In addition, the gemara in brachos mentions an amora who actually saw demons and was harmed by them. The gemara was very obviously not talking about microscopic germs. You also (somewhat condescendingly) write "so the fact that most people don't believe in demons don't exist doesn't dishonor them in any way". You're absolutely right in this, as the fact that most people dont believe in them proves absolutely nothing.

Comment: @Phil You can see Jewish sources for the fact that they don't exist elsewhere on this page. You may consider this answer a _limmud zechut_ as to how to understand the words of Chazal according to those opinions.

Comment: Incidentally, @ShmuelBrin washing hands before bread is related to Tumah, not Sheidim.

Comment: @DoubleAA Ariel K mentioned Tumah.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Where?

Comment: @DoubleAA "So if they said one should wash his hands to get rid of "ruach rah" or "bad spirits", it wasn't exactly wrong. Washing hands does help get rid of the "bad spirits" of bacteria."

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Which of those words means Tumah, usually translated as "ritual impurity" of the kind that a mikvah and the like are used to remove?

Comment: They actually have a name for the Sheid in the morning. Did they pull it out of the hat?

Comment: @halevi unlikely, though they might have. How does anything get named? Pertusis? Tetanus? Polio? Names develop for phenomena naturally. Certainly Chazal would have used a meaningful name to describe the phenomenon in question, even if the name is inherently arbitrary. (Lehavdil, would you find any value in the argument "Zeus has a name, so he must be real"? Of course not. Names develop for concepts, and we all know that.)

Answer (score 4):

The Meiri reinterprets "mazikin" and the like wherever they appear in Shas as anthing from the evil inclination to thoughts of heresy. See [here](https://seforimblog.com/2014/06/demythologising-rabbinic-aggada/) which lists instances of such reinterpretation by the Meiri.

Comment: Commentless downvoters: unlike shedim I know you exist. You are welcome to disagree with the Meiri, but I am not sure why you downvote his opinion; especially as it was shared by the greatest halachic codifier of all time.

Answer (score 2):

Ralbag writes that *sheidim* are imaginary. He goes a step further than most other authorities who deny the existence of *sheidim* and actually attempts to prove that the Sages themselves (despite all their discussions about *sheidim*) believed that *sheidim* are imaginary.

The Talmud records the following about *sheidim*:

**[Berachot 43b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=43b&format=pdf)**

> ואמר רב זוטרא בר טוביה אמר רב אבוקה כשנים וירח כשלשה איבעיא להו אבוקה
>   כשנים בהדי דידיה או דילמא אבוקה כשנים לבר מדידיה ת"ש וירח כשלשה אי
>   אמרת בשלמא בהדי דידיה שפיר אלא אי אמרת לבר מדידיה ארבעה למה לי והאמר
>   מר לאחד נראה ומזיק לשנים נראה ואינו מזיק לשלשה אינו נראה כל עיקר אלא
>   לאו שמע מינה אבוקה כשנים בהדי דידיה שמע מינה
>
> R. Zutra b. Tobiah further said in the name of Rab: A torch is as good
>   as two [persons] and moonlight as good as three. The question was
>   asked: Is the torch as good as two counting the carrier, or as good as
>   two besides the carrier? — Come and hear: ‘Moonlight is as good as
>   three’. If now you say, ‘including the carrier there is no difficulty.
>   But if you say, ‘besides the carrier’, why do I want four, seeing that
>   a Master has said: To one [person] an evil spirit may show itself and
>   harm him; to two it may show itself, but without harming them; to
>   three it will not even show itself? We must therefore say that a torch
>   is equivalent to two including the carrier; and this may be taken as
>   proved. ([Soncino translation](https://halakhah.com/pdf/zeraim/Berachoth.pdf))

Ralbag argues that if *sheidim* actualy existed then this description would not be true:

**Commentary to Deuteronomy 32:17**

> והנה הכונה בשניהם הדמות הדמוים הכוזבים כי ענין מציאות השד הוא דמיון
>   לבד ולזה אמרו רז"ל לאחד נראה ומזיק לשנים נראה ואינו מזיק לשלשה אינו
>   נראה ואינו מזיק ואלו היה ענין שהיה לו מציאות בעצמו היה נראה לשלשה כמו
>   שהוא נראה לאחד או לשנים
>
> And the intent of both of them is the imagining of false imaginations.
>   For the existence of the *sheid* is merely an imagination. That is why
>   the Sages say, "to one it appears and harms, to two it appears but
>   does not harm, and to three it does not appear nor harm". Now if the
>   fact was that it has its own existence, it would appear to three just
>   like it appears to one or two.

Answer (score 1):

Demons as they appear in the Bavli seem to be a Babylonian belief because:

- The Yerushalmi hardly mentions them
- The Babylonians were quite
  concerned with protecting themselves from demons as we see from their
  [incantation bowls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incantation_bowl)
- The name Lilith (one of the demons) is thought to derive from *lilitu*, an Akkadian word meaning "spirits"

There are a few occurrences of terms in the Tanach referring to demons. The only instance in the Torah of the word *shed* is in Devarim 32:17:

> יִזְבְּח֗וּ לַשֵּׁדִים֙ לֹ֣א אֱלֹ֔הַ אֱלֹהִ֖ים לֹ֣א יְדָע֑וּם חֲדָשִׁים֙ מִקָּרֹ֣ב בָּ֔אוּ לֹ֥א שְׂעָר֖וּם אֲבֹתֵיכֶֽם׃

That verse plainly states that demons have no power. Is that because they don't exist?

Comment: The verse doesn't say that demons don't have power. The simple understanding is that they are "not gods," and Onkoles translates, "they slaughtered for demons to no avail." Yes, many held that demons aren't real (notably Rambam, Meiri, and Ralbag), but you can't prove that from this verse.