# How could boiling 3 eggs at a time help?

Tags: minhag, number, kashrut-kosher, cooking-bishul, eggs

A lot of people have a custom of boiling 3 eggs at a time, as mentioned [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12644/why-do-some-people-have-a-custom-to-boil-only-odd-numbers-of-eggs), among any other places.

One reason given for this practice is that if one egg turns out to be unkosher, the remaining two kosher eggs will be a majority against the prohibited taste, and they and the pot will remain kosher.

I do not understand this reasoning. If you boiled 3 eggs and cracked one open and found a *neveila* chicken inside, it is totally clear to me that everything would be prohibited.  Kashrus 101: You need **60 parts kosher** to nullify the 1 part unkosher!  So what good does it do to have 3 eggs?

Is this practice really justifiable by that reason or not?

Comment: Three eggs make up 100%. One egg is 33.3%and the other two add up to 66.6%. No? 2/3==10/15 > 9/15==60%

Comment: @CHM - 60% != 1/60.  You need 60 parts kosher to nullify the forbidden taste, i.e. 98.4%

Comment: @Shauk ah Ok. Wondered.

Answer (score 3):

There are two cases I can think of in which having a majority of eggs will help.

1. If you mix up the eggs and don't remember which was the non-kosher one, you can have any of them if rov were kosher
2. If the eggs got mixed up, but they all taste the same, then you only need a rov (51%) to permit the entire thing ([Yoreh Deah 109:1](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A7%D7%98)).

Comment: the second is probably the reason

Comment: That's talking about yavesh b'yavesh, where there's no taste transfer.  Our case is where one part treif was *cooked* with 2 parts kosher.  In which case you need 60:1 to nullify the taste.  Yoreh Deah 109:2 - thanks for the link!

Comment: @Shaul ba clarified that they all have the same taste. (I can't vouch for the metziut.) Also, are you sure taste transfers through an eggshell?

Comment: @DoubleAA - have you ever had a chullent with whole eggs in it?  The eggs fully absorb the meat taste.  So yes, eggshells are porous.

Comment: @DoubleAA - Regarding them all having the same taste, that's exactly the case that YD 109:2 is dealing with, where you have min b'mino, i.e. the same taste, and you still require 60:1 to nullify the issur.