# What is the source of a minhag not to boil a single egg?

Tags: minhag, cooking-bishul

I have heard that some people have a minhag to prohibit boiling just one egg in a pot. What is the source or reason for this? Is this a kashrut concern, or something specific about eggs?

Comment: Possible dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12644/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18076/759

Comment: שולחן ערוך יורה דעה  סימן ק"ז

Answer (score 1):

[This dinonline answer](http://dinonline.org/2010/05/02/boiling-eggs/) explains the thinking ... (who knew?)

> Some have a custom to boil at least three together.
>
> (The idea behind this is that in case one of the eggs has a drop of
>   blood in it, which cannot be discovered seeing as the egg will be
>   eaten without inspecting it inside, it would be Battel in the majority
>   of two to one. This helps only for kosher eggs which are assumed to 
>   have no blood spots. This is not permitted if it is known for certain
>   that one or more of the eggs is not kosher.)

Comment: This reasoning doesn't make much sense. If you can't taste the blood, it's batel in one egg. And if you can taste the blood it's not batel in 100

Comment: @double: if you're worried that the blood is the beginning of a chicken then the problem is not just the blood but the whole egg.