# Spilling water from a full cup?

Tags: halacha, minhag, mysticism-kabbalah

When I've been to yeshiva, I've seen bochurs filling a cup with water or juice all the way and spilling a bit from the top in the trash can. At first I thought it was random but then noticed a lot of them were doing it. Whats going on exactly? Is this in my imagination, or is it a minhag, kabbalistic or not. Any citations?

Comment: I imagine that as they fill it up they don't think about the fact that they will then have to carry it to their seat, and then when they begin walking realize they are spilling, and dump some out.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3934/where-does-the-custom-to-spill-of-from-a-drink-come-from

Comment: @jake Looks like a dupe?

Comment: Doesn't that only explain when the cup was not filled up just now?  The Gemara cited there would not explain filling a cup and then immediately pouring out of it.  If the concern is that immediate, one should be pouring before every sip.