# Sheidim after the Baal Shem Tov

Tags: geography, sheidim-demons, baal-shem-tov

According to the [Minchas](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=4714&st=&pgnum=71) [Elazar](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=4714&st=&pgnum=72), the Baal Shem Tov evicted the Sheidim from where humans live. Does that mean that they are still located in the wilderness areas and one must be "choshesh" for them there?

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/729/sheidim-fact-or-fiction

Comment: That is what the word "Yishuv" would imply.

Comment: @msh210 Why did you tag this [geography]?

Comment: @WAF, it's a question about settled versus unsettled areas, i.e. a question about geography. Innit?

Answer (score 2):

According to a very good, learned Chabad rabbi and a very good, learned Yeshivish rabbi who went to the Mir Yeshiva and learned from R. Noach Weinberg and R. Moshe Feinstein, the Baal Shem Tov evicted most of the shedim.  They are not allowed to be near people.

But, just to be on the safe side, it's good not to go to an abandoned house or building, other than getting hurt by something falling, "wild animals" seem to inhabit such places.  Also, where a tragedy happened in a home, you should sell the house. Nor should you buy a house if  you find out there was a murder, suicide, etc.  Even the goyim are careful about such things.

Comment: @Miller. Did Baal Shem Tov evict most of the shédim in the world or only in one place?  I read somewhere recently here that he evicted shédim only from one place.