# May a person sit on a tree stump?

Tags: halacha, standing-sitting, trees, superstition

Can one sit on a tree stump or is there a spiritual danger?

I remember hearing such a thing, but I don't remember where.

Comment: You realize that the vast majority of works don't explicitly mention that they think this is permitted because they found it quite obvious.

Comment: Why do you say that?

Comment: What's the alternative? They all forgot?

Comment: I know it is a shabbas dispute,but stam I dk,could be made up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pesachim 111b - If one steps over a [fallen] palm tree - if it was cut down, he will be killed; if it was uprooted, he will die. If he put his foot on it, there is no problem.

doesn't say about sitting but this is probably the root of that statement. Furthermore, I was told that all the demons were banished by the maharsha, so this does not seem to apply today. someone please source this last statement.

Comment: I heard that it was the Baal Shem Tov, though it's possible a corruption of [this](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15614&st=&pgnum=206) story.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/729/sheidim-fact-or-fiction

Comment: `doesn't say about sitting but this is probably the root of that statement` What? Are you saying sitting is a problem or not? Either way, what is your evidence?

Comment: ` Furthermore, I was told that all the demons were banished by the maharsha, so this does not seem to apply today.` a) Who says demons exist? b) Who says they have anything to so with this passage in the Gemara c) Were you told that it does not apply, ir is that your own deduction?