# What is the Jewish belief regarding evil spirits?

Tags: evil-resha, heaven, sheidim-demons, ayin-hara-evil-eye, ruach-rah

What do Jews believe about ghosts and evil spirits? It seem to me that the Bible gives clear definition about the fact that they are real. What do Jews believe about this?

Comment: First things first, if you are really considering conversion, find a rabbi.  You will most likely find more satisfactory answers asking someone in person than asking an online forum of strangers.  Second, welcome, and thank you for bringing your question here.

Comment: Seth, where are ghosts and evil spirits mentioned in the Bible?

Comment: @Ephraim Regarding "ghosts", how about [*Sh'muel* I, ch. 28](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt08a28.htm), for example.

Comment: Hi Evaldas! Can you [include](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/32094/edit) some examples of where you think the Bible gives clear definitions of this?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/729/sheidim-fact-or-fiction?lq=1

Comment: @Ephraim, you should ask the OP.  I only edited it to make it work with the site. I even changed the assertion that they are real to "it seems to me..."

Comment: @SethJ, I think your tagging presupposes some answers. The question doesn't ask about _ayin hara_ or _ruach ra_ or _shedim_ or heaven, and I doubt the asker had any of those things (as understood in Judaism) in mind. (I agree with the [tag:evil-resha] tagging, though, since the question asks about evil spirits.)

Comment: Then said Saul unto his servants: 'Seek me a woman that divineth by a ghost, that I may go to her, and inquire of her.' And his servants said to him: 'Behold, there is a woman that divineth by a ghost at En-dor.'Samuel 28..7