# Do Jews believe demons can eat people

Tags: sheidim-demons, superstition

Is there any mention in Jewish scripture of demons being capable of eating human beings? I am asking this question because it is found in other religions.

Comment: Why do you think there would be?  Have you encountered this idea somewhere in (or attributed to) Judaism?  If so, please [edit] that into your question.  Thanks.  Also, if you haven't seen it yet, you might want to check out our short [tour] -- it explains how the site works and what we're looking for here.

Comment: http://www.sefaria.org/Gittin.68a where ashamadai swallows Shlomo

Comment: I think the real question is, can people (specifically, Jews that keep kosher) eat demons? That's a Jewish question, @MonicaCellio

Comment: It would seem from the meforshim that the "men"-angels that came to avrohom only pretended to eat that the supernatural doesn't eat

Answer (score 1):

**Demons in Judaism are seen as spiritual forces - as such they cannot eat human beings.** I did not find any reference to demons eating human beings anywhere in traditional sources.

R Louis Jacobs writes in [The Jewish Religion: A Companion](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198264631) (see [here](http://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/do-jews-believe-in-demons/#))

> Demons are supernatural, malevolent beings with the power to cause
>   hurt to humans. Belief in demons, though not very pronounced in Jewish
>   life and thought, is still prevalent, in a semi-comical way, at the
>   level of folklore. Even some of the learned feel compelled to accept,
>   perhaps not too seriously, belief in demons because this belief is
>   implied in the Talmud in many places.
>
> [...]
>
> Some of the medieval thinkers accepted the belief in demons. Others
>   rejected the belief as contrary to the doctrine of divine providence.
>   Why should God have surrendered His control of the universe, on some
>   occasions, into the power of such creatures?
>
> Abraham Ibn Ezra rejects entirely the notion that demons really exist.
>   Maimonides either ignores the talmudic references to demons or gives
>   these a rationalistic explanation; as, for example, when he
>   understands the mishnaic reference to an ‘evil spirit’ against which a
>   light can be put out even on the Sabbath, to mean a spirit of
>   melancholy.
>
> Menahem Meiri generally follows a similar demythologizing tendency
>   when he understands the talmudic reference to warding off the demons
>   by reciting the Shema before retiring as meaning that evil thoughts
>   invade the mind at bedtime and these can successfully be dispelled
>   through the recitation of the Shema.
>
> [...]
>
> Belief in demons is thus generally present but very peripheral in the
>   Jewish scheme. No representative thinker, for instance, ever thought
>   of dubbing Ibn Ezra a heretic because he refused to believe in demons.
>   Needless to say, sophisticated Jewish thinkers who did believe in the
>   existence of demons did not think of these as little devils with
>   forked tails breathing fire but **as spiritual forces which God has
>   unleashed in the world for purposes of His own, or as harmful
>   psychological processes which take place in the human mind.**

---

This being said there is a statement in the Talmud ([Chagiga 16](http://www.sefaria.org/Chagigah.16a.18?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all)a) stating that demons have three characteristics in common with people

> They eat and drink like humans, they are fruitful and multiply [ie.
>   they have children] like humans, and they die like humans.

but it is not further developed and there is no example of a demon eating people anywhere in the Talmud.

Finally see this [related question on MiYodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/729/sheidim-are-they-fact-or-fiction) and complete [overview](http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/Judaism/demons.html) taken from Encyclopedia Judaica.

Comment: http://www.sefaria.org/Gittin.68a have you seen this where Ashmadai swallows Shlomo

Comment: @ray I saw it (now :->) on 68b but it is not clear this is litteral, Mesoras Hashas says he swallowed Solomon's ring - need to study this some more

Comment: I have one in my house. constantly breaking stuff. 2 of my kids saw it. no joke

Comment: @ray did he eat anyone yet?