# Misplacing things and Shedim

Tags: sources-mekorot, sheidim-demons, lost-and-found

Are there any sources in Judaism that explain that when you put something down and you lose it straight after, shedim have taken it and misplaced it to mess with you?

Not sure if this is a good question but I lost something right after I put it down in front of me and this question came to mind.

Comment: Is there a reason you believe shedim are involved? Just curious I've never heard anything like that before.

Comment: Well, sometimes things just goes missing right as you look away from it or something, as if its fallen into another dimension or something, so I'm just thinking, maybe, it could be shedim or just something that's messing with us, also shedim are known to move things, sometimes things just move by themselves..

Comment: The Talmud ([Berachot 6a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=6&format=pdf)) lists several phenomena that are attributed to sheidim, but disappearing objects is not one of them.

Comment: Note that this question presupposes  the existence of Sheidim. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/729/sheidim-are-they-fact-or-fiction/9746#9746

Comment: Shedim do exist though...