# Medicine Under the Bed

Tags: halacha, food, medicine, ruach-rah

Although the [Shulchan Aruch YD (116:5)](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.116.5?vhe=Ashlei_Ravrevei:_Shulchan_Aruch_Yoreh_Deah,_Lemberg,_1888&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes

> - ולא יתן תבשיל ולא משקים תחת המטה מפני שרוח רעה שורה עליהם - don't put cooked food or drinks under the bed due to ruach ra'ah

does that issue apply to medicines?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/729/7303

Comment: Rember that the Shulchan Arukh has many mystical laws which Maimonides' Mishneh Torah left out. . . .